# Identifying menu system

Tags: dos

Back when I was a kid, we used an old MS-dos system to navigate programs, menus and games. All I can seem to remember is that we started the program by typing "menu" (or it was in the autoexec). I can't recall further about the name.

This was back in the beginning of the 90'es, but the system could have been developed earlier, but I recall using the `cd` and `cd..` to navigate earlier than that.

I also remember that you could edit the menus by adding/removing items by pressing SHIFT-F[x] (I could be wrong about the shift, but it was an modifier and an F-key), and an item was added by modifying a number of batch-commands. This could either be a new page of menues or a command to a program.

My memory tells me that it looks something like this;
[image]

Can anyone tell me more about what this program was called and maybe even if it is available as download somewhere?

(Edit: Updated title)

Answer (score 0):

I remember **DrMenu** and **Fixed Disk Organizer** (from IBM) but I don't remember their appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a similar program on my fathers PC (or rather AT) back in the late 80's/early 90's. I think it was made by Scandinavian PC Systems, or SPCS for short. I doubt Visma (that now own the brand SPCS) have it for download somewhere, and my answer is not a complete answer but I can not add a comment so I hope you excuse me for trying to help out in this way.